# about compactness of the set

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Any thoughts on the reason II is correct? I could rule out I and III, though. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

See the definition and basic properties of [limit point compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact), which is equivalent to compactness in any metric space.